# Issue downloading Truffle

Tags: truffle, command-line

I know that the command to download Truffle is 'npm install -g truffle'. When I enter this command using the command prompt, which website does it download the packages from? Does it download from GitHub?

This is because, in my organisation, we get access to websites on demand basis. So I am not able to download Truffle using command prompt as the website is not whitelisted.

Also, is there any method to install Truffle without using command prompt?

Comment: you can go to the Truffle Github and download the project and use it

Comment: I am wondering how to do that. A detailed explanation would be helpful.